# Linux: How to monitor incoming pings

Tags: linux, logging, ping, icmp

Can I somehow monitor incoming pings on a Linux machine? netcat doesn't seem to support that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `tcpdump ip proto \\icmp` to monitor incoming pings (ICMP echo requests)

Comment: works in macos as well. you might need to use `sudo`

Comment: does this also log ipv6  pings?

Comment: I guess you would specify `icmp6`

Answer (score 3):

You could setup a rule in iptables that logs icmp packets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something nicer than tcpdump (GUI and stuff), you can try with Wireshark.